# Freeze screen while window reloads

Tags: jquery, time, window

How can i freeze the screen while doing a window reload. So the screen is unclickable in that time.

```
var nTime = 1 * 50;
window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);
```

I'm using this to reload my screen. But i would like to make the screen unclickable while doing the location.reload.

With the help of Réne Roth. i've found an answer to this:

```
$( "head" ).addClass( "loadDiv" );
var nTime = 1 * 50;
window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);
```

class Loaddiv:

```
    .loadDiv{
    display: block;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 6000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an overlay div with

```
position:fixed
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

and a background of your choice which you make visible/invisible when you load/unload the page.

Comment: I'm not here to do your work for you, just point you in the right direction. Add that div right at the beginning and then use jQuery `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` to show/hide that overlay.

Comment: Thats true. i found another way to do it made an edit in the question. Thank you for your help